# How can I get the data from an array that is returned by a method?

Tags: php

I have a method that does cool magical stuff and then returns my results in the form of an array.

So for instance

```
public function somemethod()
{
    some stuff that builds an array

    return $stuff;
}
```

If you do a

```
$s = stuff();
print_r($s->somemethod());
```

You get something like

```
array('a' => 'hi', 'b' => 'hello', 'c' => 'konnichiwa')
```

How can I access each array element?

```
$s->somemethod()->a?
```

`$s->somemethod()['a']` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use foreach:

```
foreach($s->somemethod() as $key => $value)
  //process $key and $value
}
```

or 1 by 1:

```
$arr = $s->somemethod();
$arr['a']
// $arr['b']
// $arr['c']
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply do this:

```
$a = $s->somemethod();
echo( $a[ "a" ] );
```

Answer (score 1):

You have three options:

**Access an element directly**

```
$a = $s->somemethod();
echo $a['a'];
```

**Loop over all elements**

```
$a = $s->somemethod();
foreach ($a as $key => $value)
{
    echo $key . ': ' $value
};
```

**Move the elements into variables**

```
list($a, $b, $c) = $s->somemethod();
```

Comment: interesting to use the `list()` to bad that can't be used in a more dynamic way without having to hardcode variable names

Comment: What do you want? You can skip parameters and if your function returns more parameters they are ignored. `list($a, , $c) = array(1,2,3,4)`. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php

Answer (score 0):

```
function objectToArray( $object ){
if( !is_object( $object ) && !is_array( $object ) ){
  return $object;}
 if( is_object( $object ) ){
  $object = get_object_vars( $object );}
   return array_map( 'objectToArray', $object );}
```

Comment: can i add that function to the method?

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE: PHP 5.4 is <del>not</del> released <del>yet</del> now**

In PHP 5.4 you can directly use the following:

```
echo $s->somemethod()['a'];
```

Comment: i'm impatiently waiting those 12 more days!

Comment: So much power, no responsibilities :P